# Change face for non-selected ivy items

Tags: faces, ivy

I'd like to change the foreground color of non-current ivy items. The only way that I've found to do that so far is to define my own `ivy-format-function` like this:

```
(defun aj/ivy-format-function-line (cands)
"Transform CANDS into a string for minibuffer."
  (ivy--format-function-generic
   (lambda (str)
     (ivy--add-face (concat str "\n") 'ivy-current-match))
   (lambda (str)
     (ivy--add-face (concat str "\n") 'ivy-not-current))
   cands
   ""))
```

Unfortunately, this prevents `ivy-minibuffer-match-face-1`'s foreground color from taking effect (it should be white and bold) because `ivy-not-current` takes precedence. Is there a better way to do this?

[image: ivy example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work as I want, though if there's a better/more official way I'm all ears.

```
(defun aj/ivy-format-function-line (cands)
  "Transform CANDS into a string for minibuffer."
  (ivy--format-function-generic
   (lambda (str)
     (ivy--add-face (concat str "\n") 'ivy-current-match))
   (lambda (str)
     (let ((s (concat str "\n")))
       (font-lock-append-text-property 0 (length s) 'face 'ivy-not-current s)
       s))
   cands
   ""))
```